# MySQL экспорт нескольких таблиц одновременно

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Здравствуйте!

В базе данных есть 50 таблиц. Нужно сделать экспорт 20-ти из них.

Можно ли как-нибудь с помощью PhpMyAdmin создать дамп быстро? Не заходя на страницу каждой таблицы в раздел `экспорт`. Например, проставив нужные таблицы галочками, сразу сохранить группу.

Или хотя бы через консоль как можно сделать напечатав несколько названий вручную?

Либо есть альтернативные способы? Какие, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да, такой способ есть. Вы можете выбрать пункт "Экспорт" на странице базы данных, переключиться с быстрого режима на обычный и в разделе Таблицы выбрать галки напротив тех таблиц, которые хотите включить в SQL-дамп.

Comment: Я вопрос прочитать не успел :) +1 за скорость :)